# Can I safely ignore error "The event 'ContainerManipulationDelta' is not a RoutedEvent."

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2015

I am maintaining a WPF application for both Surface and Desktop that has the following in one of the XAML files:

```
<Style x:Key="infoBoxItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type s:ScatterViewItem}">
            <EventSetter Event="ContainerManipulationDelta"
                         Handler="ScatterViewItem_PositionChanged" />
```

In VS2015 I get the error "The event 'ContainerManipulationDelta' is not a RoutedEvent." when building the project. The source of the error is Build, but the build does not fail. The error occurs when opening the XAML in Designer view.

However, ContainerManipulationDelta is a routed event according documentation, just not a RoutedEvent.

I would like to know if I can safely ignore this message. It probably cannot be suppressed, since it has no number.

Previously, in VS2010 the error was not shown. The only other difference is the target .NET platform: 4.6.2 instead of 4.0. The Surface SDK is the same: 2.0.

**Update Nov 1, 2016:** 
I debugged the handler code and figured out it works just fine. However, due to the error the XAML cannot be viewed in Designer mode. That annoys me just a tiny bit.

Comment: Not sure, but does it help to write `Event="ScatterContentControlBase.ContainerManipulationDelta"`?

Comment: @Clemens, I tried, but it gave me 2 new errors, of which one kind of suggested what you proposed: _"ScatterContentControlBase is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) project."_ and _"Cannot resolve the Style Event 'ContainerManipulationDelta'. Verify that the owning type is the Style's TargetType, or use Class.Property syntax to specify the Event."_. If I use `ScatterViewItem.ContainerManipulationDelta`, I get the same messages for ScatterViewItem.